# Need help understanding Audio in Expo

Tags: android, react-native, audio, expo

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Even if it's only a link to a useful article or tutorial.

I'm trying to get a grasp on handling audio that is pulled from a website. I have done my best to create a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@tohzt/f3e2dc) that is similar to my situation.

If you look at the snack, you can see that line 10 of PlayerScreen.js has shouldPlay: set to false. If I set this to true then the audio file will begin playing as soon as you enter PlayerScreen.

The problem is that this is the only way I have managed to get the file to play, and I have no idea how to get it to stop. Ideally, I would start the file with a play button, and pause with a pause. I just don't know how to store the audio into an object that I can look into. Such that I can manipulate its play state and see the duration and current position.

Comment: Bump...
Still haven't found a solution to this problem. =(